# single event handler for all checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, controls

I'm trying to easily make custom checkboxes. I want to draw an image on top of every checkbox by it's checked state. How can I create a **single** event handler for **all** checkboxes? I have a lot of checkboxes and I don't want to write each event handler for it:

```
    private void checkbox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16);
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.checkbox_checked, rect);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.checkbox_unchecked, rect);
        }
    }
    private void checkbox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16);
        if (checkbox2.Checked)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.checkbox_checked, rect);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.checkbox_unchecked, rect);
        }
    }
    // etc...
```

Comment: if this is WPF, you can handle this in the parent's checked or unchecked handler, using the event bubbling mechanism.

Comment: refer to the book: WPF unleashed, P161

Comment: @David oh, just noticed. No, it's not WPF, it's windows forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer myself. It's easier than manually assigning paint event to every checkbox because it's done programmatically.

```
public void SetAllCheckboxes(Control where)
{
    foreach (Control control in where.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType().Name == "CheckBox")
            control.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.checkbox_Paint);
        else if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            SetAllCheckboxes(control);
    }
}
```

and then just in call it:

```
SetAllCheckboxes(this);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign this handler to all checkboxes. Notice how I cast `sender` to `CheckBox`  in order to get the control that triggered the event.

```
private void checkbox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = sender as CheckBox // Here you get the current checkbox
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16);
    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.checkbox_checked, rect);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.checkbox_unchecked, rect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use same method any number of times, just assign it in Paint event(via designer or from code).

To get current checkbox cast sender to checkbox.

```
private void checkbox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is Windows Forms based on the context?

You select each `checkbox` (you can multi-select on the forms designer), click the lightning bolt in the `Properties` panel, find the Paint event and put your method name: `checkbox1_Paint`
, in there.